# Real-time loopback interface packet capture on Windows with RawCap, Wireshark, and some pipe utility

Tags: windows-7, wireshark, pipe

After stumbling across another Super User post about loopback packet capture on Windows, I was directed to [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap), a utility that provides pseudo-capture of loopback packets.  RawCap writes to libpcap files that Wireshark can read.  This is great for capturing and then displaying the captured data, but I have a use case where I would like to view these packets captured in real time.

[Wireshark supports streaming packets from STDIN](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes#Stdin), but RawCap doesn't support directing its output to STDOUT.  It can only write to a file.  RawCap does support an option to disable buffering, writing each packet to the file as it comes in.

Is there some third utility I can use, similar to `tail` that will output contents of a file as it is being written to under windows, so I can pipe from a RawCap capture file to Wireshark in real time?

```
RawCap -> Intermediate File -> Tail-Like Utility for Binary -> Wireshark STDIN
```

Comment: what do you mean by similar to tail?  does this command help? tee  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)

Comment: by the way, does wireshark even display in real time? I tried getting it to when it was ethereal years ago and it didn't. and there's nothing about it here http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/4052/show-packet-data-in-real-time-during-capture  ah i see http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Pipes

Comment: @barlop Strange... Ethereal has always displayed in real-time for me.  Tee doesn't help, since RawCap doesn't write to STDOUT.  If it did, I could just pipe it directly to Wireshark.  I need some sort of tool that can read from a file as it is being written to, and send the data to Wireshark.  If Windows supported named pipes, I'd just go that route.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It turns out I can actually just use `tail` for this.  It isn't ideal since it's probably looking for `\n` in the data before outputting, but there is enough data in packet captures to make this work it seems.  Here's what I did:

1. Install [UnixUtilities](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) to get a port of tail for Win32.
2. Install [RawCap](http://www.netresec.com/?page=RawCap)
3. Install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html)
4. `rawcap -f 127.0.0.1 localhost.pcap`
5. `tail -c +1 -f localhost.pcap | wireshark -k -i -`

Because RawCap needs your initial terminal, you'll need to start a second one for the tail.  Also, obviously substitute in any paths you need.

A bit of a hack, but it works!  I can only hope that Wireshark will include shelling RawCap as a more direct method in a future release.

Answer (score -1):

Do give a fuller answer than mine, showing how Wireshark shows packets in real time, but the command that perhaps you are looking for is [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29).

```
$ ls -l | tee file.txt | head -n 1
```

... dumps to screen, saves as a file, and pipes what is dumped to screen to head.

Comment: This won't work for me.  The whole problem is that RawCap doesn't support writing to STDOUT and cannot be piped into Wireshark.  RawCap only writes to files, so I need some way to stream from that file while it is being written to, into STDIN on Wireshark.